# Unit-testing MPI Programs with gtest

Tags: c++, mpi, googletest

I'm parallelizing an already existent application that uses gTest with MPI. In MPI programs, the first thing to do is to initialize the environment with a call to

```
MPI_Init( int *argc, char ***argv )
```

At the end of an MPI program the root process should also call MPI_Finalize. How can I write unit-tests for such an application using Google Test?

In particular, how do I access argc, and argv from the tests *before* gTest modifies them.

Right now I'm doing:

```
int argc = 0;
char** argv = NULL;
boost::mpi::environment env(argc,argv);

TEST(component_test, test_name) {
  // stuff using mpi
}
```

and feels wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you sure you want to access the `argc` and `argv` values *before* googletest? They are modified to remove googletest specific arguments such as `--gtest_filter` so that the application does not see them.

I think what you want to do is simply using the following snippet as your `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int result = 0;

    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    result = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    MPI_Finalize();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does InitGoogleTest remove arguments that are not relevant to gTest?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Only the gtest arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Just add to @rmhartog's answer.

You probably also want to add below to leave only one listener for printing before RUN_ALL_TESTS(), otherwise, the stdout messages mingle.

```
::testing::TestEventListeners& listeners =
    ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();
if (world.rank() != 0) {
    delete listeners.Release(listeners.default_result_printer());
}
```